# Cosine similarity of word2vec more than 1

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I used a word2vec algorithm of spark to compute documents vector of a text.

I then used the `findSynonyms` function of the model object to get synonyms of few words.

I see something like this:

```
w2vmodel.findSynonyms('science',4).show(5)
+------------+------------------+
|        word|        similarity|
+------------+------------------+
|     physics| 1.714908638833209|
|     fiction|1.5189824643358183|
|neuroscience|1.4968051528391833|
|  psychology| 1.458865636374223|
+------------+------------------+
```

I do not understand why the cosine similarity is being calculated as more than 1. Cosine similarity should be between 0 and 1 or max -1 and +1 (taking negative angles).

Why it is more than 1 here? What's going wrong here?

Answer (score 4):

You should normalize the word vectors that you got from `word2vec`, otherwise you would get unbounded dot product or cosine similarity values.

From [Levy et al., 2015](http://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q15-1016) (and, actually, most of the literature on word embeddings):

> Vectors are normalized to unit length before they are used for similarity calculation, making cosine similarity and dot-product equivalent.

**How to do normalization?**

You can do something like below.

```
import numpy as np

def normalize(word_vec):
    norm=np.linalg.norm(word_vec)
    if norm == 0: 
       return word_vec
    return word_vec/norm
```

**References**

- [Should I do normalization to word embeddings from word2vec if I want to do semantic tasks?](https://www.quora.com/Should-I-do-normalization-to-word-embeddings-from-word2vec-if-I-want-to-do-semantic-tasks)
- [Should I normalize word2vec's word vectors before using them?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/177905/should-i-normalize-word2vecs-word-vectors-before-using-them)

> Update: Why cosine similarity of word2vec is greater than 1?

According to this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/178809), in spark implementation of word2vec, `findSynonyms` doesn't actually return cosine distances, but rather cosine distances times the norm of the query vector.

The ordering and relative values are consistent with the true cosine distance, but the actual values are all scaled.

Comment: Thanks. But quick question. If I normalize vectors and then take cosine similarity it is akin to taking dot product only. If I don't normalize and then take cosine similarity, in the formula for cosine similarity we do divide the dot product by the norms of each vector. So there is normalization happening while calculating cosine similarity. So am not sure why would one specifically require to normalize it. 

It would be same formula in the end and calculation should be same

Comment: Thanks I know the normalization part. But my question why will that change the cosine similarity. The formula remains same if you normalize or don't

Comment: you are completely correct. then i believe you should check how you are computing cosine similarity! if you are using any library or package, you should make sure that the similarity is computed as you are expecting. other than that, i don't see any problem in your understanding.

Comment: I am not calculating cosine similarity. Spark Word2Vec calculates already when you call findSynonyms

Comment: right, thats why i said, you are not getting the thing you are expecting. your understanding is correct but you may not know how spark has implemented word2vec. see the update in my answer.

Comment: I checked the update and looked at the source code. It is not very clear. I have added my comment on the link of the other question you have shared.