# word2vec cosine similarity greater than 1 arabic text

Tags: nlp, arabic, word2vec, similarity

I have trained my `word2vec` model from `gensim` and I am getting the nearest neighbors for some words in the corpus. Here are the similarity scores:

```
 top neighbors for الاحتلال:
الاحتلال: 1.0000001192092896
الاختلال: 0.9541053175926208
الاهتلال: 0.872565507888794
الاحثلال: 0.8386293649673462
الاكتلال: 0.8209128379821777
```

It is odd to get a similarity greater than 1. I cannot apply any stemming to my text because the text includes many OCR spelling mistakes (I got the text from ORC-ed documents). How can I fix the issue ?

**Note** I am using `model.similarity(t1, t2)`

**This is how I trained my Word2Vec Model:**

```
    documents = list()
    tokenize = lambda x: gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(x)
    t1 = time.time()
    docs = read_files(TEXT_DIRS, nb_docs=5000)
    t2 = time.time()
    print('Reading docs took: {:.3f} mins'.format((t2 - t1) / 60))
    print('Number of documents: %i' % len(docs))

    # Training the model
    model = gensim.models.Word2Vec(docs, size=EMBEDDING_SIZE, min_count=5)
    if not os.path.exists(MODEL_DIR):
        os.makedirs(MODEL_DIR)
    model.save(os.path.join(MODEL_DIR, 'word2vec'))

    weights = model.wv.vectors
    index_words = model.wv.index2word

    vocab_size = weights.shape[0]
    embedding_dim = weights.shape[1]

    print('Shape of weights:', weights.shape)
    print('Vocabulary size: %i' % vocab_size)
    print('Embedding size: %i' % embedding_dim)
```

Below is the read_files function I defined:

```
def read_files(text_directories, nb_docs):
    """
    Read in text files
    """
    documents = list()
    tokenize = lambda x: gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(x)
    print('started reading ...')
    for path in text_directories:
        count = 0
        # Read in all files in directory
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            all_files = os.listdir(path)
            for filename in all_files:
                if filename.endswith('.txt') and filename[0].isdigit():
                    count += 1
                    with open('%s/%s' % (path, filename), encoding='utf-8') as f:
                        doc = f.read()
                        doc = clean_text_arabic_style(doc)
                        doc = clean_doc(doc)
                        documents.append(tokenize(doc))
                        if count % 100 == 0:
                            print('processed {} files so far from {}'.format(count, path))
                if count >= nb_docs and count <= nb_docs + 200:
                    print('REACHED END')
                    break
        if count >= nb_docs and count <= nb_docs:
            print('REACHED END')
            break

    return documents
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41387000/cosine-similarity-of-word2vec-more-than-1) thread but it won't help me because I rather have `arabic` and **misspelled** text

**Update**
I tried the following: (getting the similarity between the exact same word)

```
print(model.similarity('الاحتلال','الاحتلال'))
```

and it gave me the following result:

```
1.0000001
```

Comment: Can you show the exact minimal code & output for a result-over-`1.0`? For example, does `model.similarity('الاحتلال', 'الاحتلال')` show that value? (That is: the exact same string with itself? I may have mis-pasted, as I'm not a reader of Arabic nor fully-aware of R-to-L language issues.)

Comment: (Note that it may be clearer to edit your question to include this extra info, for clearer formatting, than to answer here as a comment.)

Comment: from the quantity it's "greater" than 1 (smaller than 1e-6), I would assume this is more likely to be a numeric error when calculating the similarity between two same vectors.

Comment: @gojomo I edited my question as you said, please check

Comment: @Crystina so a numeric error from my side or from ```gensim```'s side ? I edited my question above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitionally, the cosine-similarity measure should max at 1.0.

But in practice, floating-point number representations in computers have tiny imprecisions in the deep-decimals. And, especially when a number of calculations happen in a row (as with the calculation of this cosine-distance), those will sometimes lead to slight deviations from what the expected maximum or exactly-right answer "should" be.

(Similarly: sometimes calculations that, mathematically, should result in the exact same answer no matter how they are reordered/regrouped deviate slightly when done in different orders.)

But, as these representational errors are typically "very small", they're usually not of practical concern. (They are especially small in the range of numbers around -1.0 to 1.0, but can become quite large when dealing with giant numbers.)

In your original case, the deviation is just `0.000000119209289`. In the word-to-itself case, the deviation is just `0.0000001`. That is, about one-ten-millionth off. (Your other sub-`1.0` values have similar tiny deviations from perfect calculation, but they aren't noticeable.)

In most cases, you should just ignore it.

If you find it distracting to you or your users in numerical displays/logging, simply choosing to display all such values to a limited number of after-the-decimal-point digits – say 4 or even 5 or 6 – will hide those noisy digits. For example, using a Python 3 format-string:

```py
sim = model.similarity('الاحتلال','الاحتلال')
print(f"{sim:.6}")
```

(Libraries like `numpy` that work with large arrays of such floats can even set a global default for display precision – see [`numpy.set_print_options`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.set_printoptions.html) – though that shouldn't affect the raw Python floats you're examining.)

If for some reason you absolutely need the values to be capped at `1.0`, you could add extra code to do that. But, it's usually a better idea to choose your tests & printouts to be robust to, & oblivious with regard to, such tiny deviations from perfect math.

Comment: Floating-point issues are definitely a suspect, but I have an example with the `word2vec-google-news-300` model from `gensim` where the distance is 1.003 (between _horse_ and _paris_), and this seems larger than what you imply.

Comment: *Distance* or *similarity*? (Cosine-similarity maxes at `1.0`, but cosine-distance maxes at `2.0`, and if you're instead doing euclidean-distance on non-unit-normalized vectors, there's no max.) Are you suggesting `print(model.similarity('horse', 'paris'))`, using the `GoogleNews` vectors,  shows `1.003`? (I highly doubt that!)