# Word vector similarity precision

Tags: python, numpy, nlp, precision, gensim

I am trying to implement Gensim's `most_similar` function by hand but calculate the similarity between the query word and just one other word (avoiding the time to calculate it for the query word with *all* other words). So far I use

```
cossim = (np.dot(a, b)
                   / np.linalg.norm(a)
                   / np.linalg.norm(b))
```

and this is the same as the similarity result between `a` and `b`. I find this works almost exactly but that some precision is lost, for example

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
import gensim.downloader as api

model_gigaword = api.load("glove-wiki-gigaword-300")

a = 'france'
b = 'chirac'

cossim1 = model_gigaword.most_similar(a)
import numpy as np
cossim2 = (np.dot(model_gigaword[a], model_gigaword[b])
                   / np.linalg.norm(model_gigaword[a])
                   / np.linalg.norm(model_gigaword[b]))
print(cossim1)
print(cossim2)
```

Output:

```
[('french', 0.7344760894775391), ('paris', 0.6580672264099121), ('belgium', 0.620672345161438), ('spain', 0.573593258857727), ('italy', 0.5643460154533386), ('germany', 0.5567398071289062), ('prohertrib', 0.5564222931861877), ('britain', 0.5553334355354309), ('chirac', 0.5362644195556641), ('switzerland', 0.5320892333984375)]
0.53626436
```

So the most_similar function gives 0.53626441955... (rounds to 0.53626442) and the calculation with numpy gives 0.53626436. Similarly, you can see differences between the values for 'paris' and 'italy' (in similarity compared to 'france'). These differences suggest that the calculation is not being done to full precision (but it is in Gensim). How can I fix it and get the output for a single similarity to higher precision, exactly as it comes from most_similar?

TL/DR - I want to use function('france', 'chirac') and get 0.536264**4195556641**, not 0.536264**36**.

Any idea what's going on?

---

UPDATE: I should clarify, I want to know and replicate how most_similar does the computation, but for only one (a,b) pair. That's my priority, rather than finding out how to improve the precision of my cossim calculation above. I just assumed the two were equivalent.

Comment: Why is such exact correspondence in the deep low-significance digits important to you?

Comment: @gojomo Why? Because I want to compute *exactly* the way most_similar does (but for only one (a,b) pair).

Comment: You could change your code to run exactly the same code steps & routines, in the exact same order, as you can read inside the source code for `most_similar()`, then. But I'd still wonder: why do you want to match `most_similar()` exactly, into deep low-significance digits that should affect no real outcomes in any meaningful way. Given both the inherent noisiness of such learned-vector models, **and** inherent vagaries in how computers do floating-point math, it's generally **not** necessary or wise to insist on such exact correspondence. I'll explain in more depth in a full answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

To increase accuracy you can try the following:

```
a = np.array(model_gigaword[a]).astype('float128')
b = np.array(model_gigaword[b]).astype('float128')
cossim = (np.dot(a, b)
                   / np.linalg.norm(a)
                   / np.linalg.norm(b))
```

The vectors are likely to use lower-precision floats and hence there is loss precision in calculations.

However, the results I got are somewhat different to what `model_gigaword.most_similar` offers for you:

```
model_gigaword.similarity: 0.5362644
float64:  0.5362644263010196
float128: 0.53626442630101950744
```

You may want to check what you get on your machine and with your version of Python and `gensim`.

Comment: I get ```TypeError``` 'data type "float128" not understood', but anyway, my goal is not just to generate higher precision but actually to understand how the computation is done by most_similar. Apparently the code is found here https://github.com/maciejkula/glove-python/blob/749494290fdfd24379dcc2e244c583ee61808634/glove/glove.py#L273 but I cannot see how it's doing anything different

Comment: float128 may cause trouble if you are not running the code on a platform supporting such datatype (e.g. 32b Python may be missing it).

Comment: So what does ```model_gigaword.most_similar``` and ```model_gigaword.similarity``` do differently from my cossim calculation above? (Note: you can check ```most_similar``` and ```similarity``` give identical answers by expanding the precision of the answer from ```similarity``` as you showed)

Answer (score 0):

Because floating-point numbers (like the `np.float32`-typed values in these vector models) are represented using an imprecise binary approximation, none of the numbers you're working with, or displaying, are the exact decimal numbers you think they are.

The number you're seeing as `0.53626436` isn't exactly that - but some binary floating-point number very close to that number. Similarly, the number you're seeing as `0.5362644195556641` isn't exactly that – but some other binary floating-point number, ver close to that.

Further, these tiny imprecisions can mean that mathematical expressions that should under ideal circumstances give identical results to each other, no matter the order-of-evaluation, instead give slightly different results for different orders-of-evaluation. For example, we know that mathematically, `a * (b + c)` is always equal to `ab + ac`. However, if `a`, `b`, & `c` are floating-point numbers with limited precision, the results of doing the addition then multiplication, versus doing two multiplications then one addition, might vary - because the interim values would have been approximated slightly differently.

But: for nearly all domains in which these numbers are used, this tiny amount of noise shouldn't make any difference. The right policy is to ignore it, and write code that's robust to this small 'jitter' in extremely-low-significance digits - especially when *printing* or *comparing* results.

So really you should only be printing/comparing these numbers to a level of significance where they reliably agree, say, 4 digits after the decimal:

```
0.53626436 
0.5362644195556641
```

(In fact, your output already makes it look like you may have *changed the default level of display-precision in `numpy` or `python`*, because it wouldn't be typical for the results of `most_simlar()` to display with those 16 digits after the decimal.)

If you really, really wanted, as an exploration, to match the `most_similar()` results exactly, you could look at its source code. Then, perform the exact same steps, in the exact same order, using the exact same library routines, on your inputs.

(Here's the source for `most_similar()` in the current `gensim-4.0.0beta` prerelease: https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/4.0.0beta/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py#L690)

But: insisting on such exact correspondence is usually unwise, & creates more-fragile code, given the inherent imprecision in floating-point math.

See also: [another answer covering some similar issues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65327826/130288), which also points out a way to change the default displayed precision.